# Open password protected PDF

Tags: pdf, passwords, password-protection

I created a password protected PDF. I found it few days ago on my computer. Now I can't remember the password, and I really need to open this file. I tried with a few password protected remove software, and still nothing. It always ask for password. Is there any chance that I can find a solution to read it's content?

Thanks

Comment: Nope, the password is part of the encryption if you used proper software to protect it. It's the whole point of password protecting your data...

Comment: I am sure that there is a solution. I am just not sure which one can be faster

Comment: I guess that brute force will catch it

Comment: how it may happens that you create pdf and have no more source?)))